# keras prioritizes metrics or loss?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I'm struggling with understanding how keras model works.

When we train model, we give metrics(like ['accuracy']) and loss function(like cross-entropy) as arguments.
What I want to know is which is the goal for model to optimize.
After fitting, leant model maximize accuracy? or minimize loss?

Answer (score 2):

The model optimizes the loss; Metrics are only there for your information and reporting results.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_function

Note that metrics are optional, but you must provide a loss function to do training.

You can also evaluate a model on metrics that were not added during training.

Answer (score 0):

Keras models work by minimizing the loss by adjusting trainable model parameters via back propagation. The metrics such as training accuracy, validation accuracy etc are provided as information but can also be used to improve your model's performance through the use of Keras callbacks. Documentation for that is located [here.](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/) For example the callback ReduceLROnPlateau (documentation is [here](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/reduce_lr_on_plateau/)) can be used to monitor a metric like validation loss and adjust the model's learning rate if the loss fails to decrease after a certain number (patience parameter) of consecutive epochs.